# Meteor JS is giving error

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I am using `Meteor JS`.

In event I write code :

```
console.log(document.getElementsById('email_id').value);
```

My code giving error:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function

I don't know know why?

Comment: Was this really a typo?

Answer (score 1):

It is `document.getElementById`, not `Elements`.

Comment: it's giving same error:   Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByName is not a function

Comment: It is `document.getElementsByName` 

Fetching by class, name and tagname - Plural.
Fetching by id - Singular.

Comment: Thanks Kaoskeya! but i am using this code in meteor JS and i am unable to get value of textfield.

Comment: Template.reg.events({
      'click': function (event) { Console.log(document.getElementByName("txt_Email").value)     }
  });

Comment: You are _trying_ to listen to the `click` event, but you will also have to specify the element whose click you are listening to.
Lets say you have a button with id "submit", `click #button` will trigger when the button is clicked. Your `click` is never triggered. Could you add the button and see if the value logs? 
Also, `console`, lower case c and `document.getElementsByName`